# EF Code first keeps dropping and creating database in Code First in IIIS

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Following is a part of code in my DbContext that creates data and seeds data.

```
public  class labSchedulerDbContext :DbContext
    {

        static abDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new abDatabaseInitializer());

        }
        public abDbContext() :base                  (nameOrConnectionString:"abDbContext")
       {

        }

             protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
}
```

Rest of the code is just declaring models.

In my setinitializer class with seed

```
public class abDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<abDbContext>
{
.....

}
```

Code is working fine. Problem I have is when I created site in IIS and ran it. It runs fine but after few hours it will delete the database and initialize and seed data again. Thus we lose the data added. I tried to comment out lines where setinitilizer file is being called. Still didn't work. I refreshed apppool and site maybe it was cached files. But still no luck. 
Can you please tell me how I can disable the whole initializer file once a database is created so no matter what it doesn't go and drops db and create a new one. 
Cod

Comment: IMO, the idea of drop create database should be only during the development phase and not when you publish the site, to get rid from this behavior, you can surround the code by #if(DEBUG) Database.SetInitializer(...) #endif ,  you what you want is just to get rid from this problem

Comment: Are you using the same connection string while debugging this application? just wondering if perhaps you are accidentally using the wrong connection string while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this other initializer:

> [CreateDatabaseIfNotExists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679221(v=vs.113).aspx): This is default initializer. As the name suggests, it will create the database if none exists as per the configuration. However, if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer, then it will throw an exception

The only thing that you have to do is to drop the database yourself before you deploy a new version with a different model. (Provided that's what you want to do).